# Shell script with SQLite commands doesn't run from crontab

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite, shell, centos

I have a bash shell script which contains a copy, then sqlite3, a move and finally remove command. When I run the script manually - it fails with 'Error: near "/": syntax error'. I am assuming this is why the script fails to complete. The script which is failing is:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 #Setting Variables
FINAL_CSV=log_"$(date +%Y%m%d)".csv

STAGING_AREA=/opt/card_staging/

CONSUMPTION_AREA=/opt/badge_logs_final/

 # Copy latest db to staging area
cp -p log_"$(date +%Y%m%d)"* $STAGING_AREA

 # convert db to csv and select last 24 hours.
sqlite3 -header -csv /opt/card_staging/*.db "SELECT * FROM Log WHERE Date >= strftime('%s', date('now', '-1 day'));" > $STAGING_AREA/$FINAL_CSV

 # Move daily csv to consumption area
mv $STAGING_AREA/$FINAL_CSV $CONSUMPTION_AREA

 # Once complete, clean up temporary files in staging area
rm -f $STAGING_AREA/log_*
```

The strange thing is that if I enter the each of these commands manually, and then attempt to run the script, it works! Is there something I need to add to this in order 'activate' and to execute the SQLite command? I read EOP may be a solution but not sure how to include this for my simple script?

Comment: Did you run it with `bash -x script` to know exactly where it is failing?  Your she-bang line is wrong -- remove the leading space.

Comment: Here's the output from the -x:

`++ date +%Y%m%d
+ FINAL_CSV=log_20170502.csv
+ STAGING_AREA=/opt/card_staging/
+ CONSUMPTION_AREA=/opt/badge_logs_final/
++ date +%Y%m%d
+ cp -p log_20170502-020004.db /opt/card_staging/
+ sqlite3 -header -csv '/opt/card_staging/*.db' /opt/card_staging/log_20170502-020004.db 'SELECT * FROM Log WHERE Date >= strftime('\''%s'\'', date('\''now'\'', '\''-1 day'\''));'
Error: near "/": syntax error
+ mv /opt/card_staging//log_20170502.csv /opt/badge_logs_final/
+ rm -f /opt/card_staging//log_20170502-020004.db` the problem seems to be with the SQLite cmd?

Comment: The error should tell you exactly what the issue is... (eg. `$STAGING_AREA/$FINAL_CSV`)

Comment: Don't do `/opt/card_staging/*.db`. It only works when there's exactly one file, and it currently appears that you have two. One of them is literally named `*.db`, probably from a bad run previously.

Comment: You're right. `/opt/card_staging` contained the file '*.db'. I removed this, and the script runs perfectly when run manually. 

`++ date +%Y%m%d
+ FINAL_CSV=log_20170502.csv
+ STAGING_AREA=/opt/card_staging/
+ CONSUMPTION_AREA=/opt/badge_logs_final/
++ date +%Y%m%d
+ cp -p log_20170502-020004.db /opt/card_staging/
+ sqlite3 -header -csv /opt/card_staging/log_20170502-020004.db 'SELECT * FROM Log WHERE Date >= strftime('\''%s'\'', date('\''now'\'', '\''-1 day'\''));'
+ mv /opt/card_staging/log_20170502.csv /opt/badge_logs_final/
+ rm -f /opt/card_staging//log_20170502-020004.db`

Comment: Will try this from cron now!

Comment: Check your script at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: hmm.. Back to the same issue. When I run the script manually, it works, but when run from the cron it fails and creates the *.db file in /opt/card_staging. Open to suggestions as to why this isn't running properly.